# Is there any performance overhead when'RunInterval' on Puppet agent is set to 0 (continuously run)?

Tags: puppet

By default, a Puppet agent polls after every 30 minutes for any configuration changes on Puppet master. So, there is always a lag (when there is any configuration change on master) of <= 30 minutes in applying configuration changes on applicable agents.

I want the changes to be applied to agents in near real time (approximately in less than a minute). For that, I want to set 'RunInterval' to 0 on agent, so that the changes are applied in near real time.

I want to understand if there is any performance overhead associated when 'RunInterval' is set to 0 (continuously run). How do the agent functions when it is set to run continuously? Does it use some sort of long polling? Is it recommended/advisable to override the default and set 'RunInterval' to 0 (continuously run)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a good amount of overhead.

There is overhead at the master, which must handle many more requests per unit time -- perhaps as many as 200 times as many requests, depending on how long catalog runs take at the agents.  For each request, it must sync plugins with the agent, compile and return a catalog, and possibly serve files, none of which are trivial.

There is also overhead at the agent.  For each catalog run, it must at minimum go through each declared resource and test whether that resource is in the specified target state.  Doing so is non-trivial even when no changes are required.

Your strategy is more likely to fall over because of the greatly-increased demands it will place on your master than because of the extra load on the clients, but your clients will definitely feel it if they're already carrying a heavy load.

If you want the ability to *occasionally* trigger *specific servers* to sync immediately, then consider looking into mcollective.

If you want the ability to *routinely* trigger *many servers* to sync immediately, then consider switching to masterless mode, combined with mcollective or some other kind of group remote-control software.

Answer (score 0):

The puppet master will collate your puppet manifests into a single file for your client to use. If all clients are querying the puppet master at the same time, it will likely struggle under the load, provided that you have a non-trivial puppet deployment with several hundred/thousand puppet-managed servers.

What should matter to you is eventual consistency - the certainty that given enough time, the clients will converge to the desired configuration.